# Assigning condition to a sample while taking multilevel structure into account

Tags: r, assign, sampling, multi-level

I'm planning to assign one of two conditions to each respondent in my sample (such as "treatment condition" or "control condition").
50% of the sample should be assigned to the first condition, the other 50% to the second condition. The results should be noted in a new column (e.g. control or treatment)

The sample however has a multilevel structure (e.g. respondents are nested within classes).

Rather than simply splitting the whole sample randomly into the two conditions, I would like to take the class levels into account.
So 50% of each class should be in condition 1, the rest in condition 2. Logically this would also result in equally sized groups when looking at the whole sample.

To go even further, one could think of lower group levels, such as taking respondents gender within each class into account (50% of all men and 50% of all women within each class are assigned to condition 1, the rest to condition 2).

The code below shows a simplified example of a sample with 100 respondents, 5 classes (n=20 each), and a random number of male or female.

Of course, 50-50% would not always be possible due to uneven group sizes, but in that case the difference should be only 1.

Any ideas how I could take the different levels into account without having to split up the whole sample manually? (Some combination of sample and dplyr's group_by?)

## reproducible code

```
set.seed(12345)
group<-sort(rep(c("class a","class b","class c","class d","class e"), 
20))
sex<-sample(c("male", "female"), size=length(group), replace=TRUE)

test_frame<-cbind.data.frame(participant=1:length(group), group, sex)
```

Comment: This is called a "stratified random sample", if you search for that term you can find many examples, e.g., [drawing a stratified sample in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7950834/903061), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26110665/903061), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9703428/903061), etc. I'm going to mark this as a duplicate. If you have trouble with a solution, edit the question to show what you tried  (based on the duplicate) and we can help you figure it out from there.

Comment: I'd suggest starting with the `dplyr` based solution, something like `library(dplyr); test_frame %>% group_by(group, sex) %>% mutate(new_condition = ifelse(sample.int(n()) < n() / 2, "yes", "no"))` is probably what you need.

Comment: Thank you a lot, knowing the correct term helps.

A small change was needed in your solution:
`test_frame %>% group_by(group, sex) %>% mutate(new_condition = ifelse(sample.int(n()) < n() / 2+1, "yes", "no"))`
(or alternativeley, "<" becomes "<=")

That works quite well.
The only problem I see is, that groups with uneven group sizes (e.g. n=11) will by definition always have one person more assigned to the "yes" group due to the ifelse formular.

In a sample with lots of uneven groups this would accumulate and lead to larger differences in the number of participant per condition.

Comment: Yes, you could use something like this `sample.int(n()) <= round(n() / 2 + sample(c(-.1, .1), size = n(), replace = TRUE))` to randomly round up or down.