# Sampling Observations by Country in R

Tags: r, tidyr

Lets say I have a dataframe (df) that is composed of 4000 observations that are structured like so

```r
Country | Date | Log_GDP | Log_DMSP | Log_Population.
```

Each country appears multiple times in the dataframe as this is panel data. How would I go about sampling 200 random countries from this dataframe so that they can be fed into an lm() function that looks like this?

```
lm(Log_GDP ~ 1 + Log_Population + Log_DMSP+as.factor(Date),data=sampled_df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sample` function over the coutrnies

```r
rand_countries <- sample(unique(df$Country), size = 200, replacement = FALSE), ]
```

And pick these values from the dataframe

```r
sampled_df <- df[df$Country %in% rand_countries, ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are talking about stratified sampling.

In your case you need stratified sampling on column "country".

please refer to:

[How to create a stratified sample by state in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9703428/how-to-create-a-stratified-sample-by-state-in-r)